# Quotation about usefulness of good definitions in maths?

Tags: math-history

I feel like I have heard this quote somewhere, but can't remember where or by whom. I saw somewhere on this site something along the lines of "a good definition is worth a thousand proofs", but that doesn't sound quite right and was unattributed. Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Maybe you were thinking [*In mathematics: One good definition is worth a thousand calculations*](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/FiniteSpaces.pdf).

Comment: @Amzoti maybe. I had thought there might be a particular person associated with such a quote, but it might just be a common saying instead?

Comment: I have tried looking and no luck either! Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know what, it was probably this:

[A good lemma is worth a thousand theorems.](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/Opinion82.html)